# An easy regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to pick a string like `20-30` from my file.  My code:

```
terms = re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{2}',s)
```

It returns correct answers, but the sequence is not correct

my strings in my file is in sequence as bellow (from start to end of file)

```
21-40
38-25
43-22
34-31
```

but it returns:

```
34-31
21-40
38-25
43-22
```

The numbers are in unicode format

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to find `20-30` but not `30-20`?

Comment: @ruakh, no, he's saying that's an example of a string he'd want to find.

Comment: No ruakh , it return exact things that I want, but the sequence of them is not from begin to end of file. first of them is in incorrect sequence.

Comment: Can you add to your question your input, output and desired output?

Comment: need an example of "sequence not correct" the code is fine

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Test it here: http://ideone.com/UgJ9W

Comment: You are correct, but it does not work for me ! Can it be from my file structure perspective ?

Comment: @Mahdi: The problem must be either on the way from your file to `s` (try printing out `s` right before performing the `findall`; does it look like you expect?), or on the way from `terms` to what you're printing out (try printing out `terms` immediately after performing the `findall`).

Comment: The numbers is in unicode format ! Can I do something more ?

Answer (score 1):

That statement, with that string should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "21-40 38-25 43-22 34-31"
>>> terms = re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{2}',s)
>>> terms
['21-40', '38-25', '43-22', '34-31']
```

There must be something else going on. Is the input string getting manipulated some how?

Comment: No, Really it is read from a file and then I use this pattern

Comment: @Mahdi, then the file does not contain what you think it contains. Really. Try creating a new file and then **typing** (not copy-pasting!) the numbers and try again with that new file.

Comment: @Mahdi It sounds like the error might be around how the file is loaded. ave you tried printing back what the value of `s` is before applying the regex?